# How can I add a char to an istringstream?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add a char to an istringstream - as so:

```
using namespace std;
istringstream input_buffer;    
char c;

while (is.get(c)) {
    input_buffer << c;
}
```

Sadly, this results in:

```
 error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::istringstream' (aka 'basic_istringstream<char>') and 'int')
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I do it right?

Comment: You can't insert into an input stream.  You are supposed to extract from input streams.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe you could use `std::stringstream` and treat as both input and output stream.

Comment: Next time, please provide code that compiles, i.e. with all the necessary #includes. That makes it much more likely that someone provides an answer.

Comment: What is your actual objective here? Do you want to expand the range your input is supposed to use? If so, you *could* add the character using something like `is.str(is.str() + c)` although I'm not sure if the read position is appropriately positioned and it would be hideously inefficient. The proper approach to expand the input sequence would probably be a custom `std::streambuf` with the corresponding functionality and use that to initialise an `std::istream`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm trying to add a char to an `istringstream`

You cannot do that. It does not make sense either.

You are expected to read from an `istringstream` and write to an `ostringstream`.

Use `ostringstream` instead.

```
ostringstream output_buffer;    

while (is.get(c)) {
    output_buffer << c;
}
```

Comment: Or `std::stringstream` for mixed operations.

Comment: Hi RS - I'll give you the tick - but Thomas Matthews and SergeyA are the ones with the answer that works for me.  Just not written in a way I can vote for!

Comment: @headbanger, you also have option of posting an answer that works for you, with due credit given to Thomas Matthews and SergeyA, and accept that answer.